# Sending variable to another class with MVC model using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Would like the output from **screen_output_var** inside the *class Model* to be sent to the *class View* while the loop is in operation to give an update to the status of the copy function. I want to do this while still keeping the MVC model intact, that is the model is unaware of the controller or view class.

```
class Model: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_output_var = ''

    def copy_function(self, dest_dir):
        file_increment = 1
        for file in list:
            self.screen_output_var = f'Copying file {file_increment} of {len(list)}' <---- PROBLEM HERE
            h = os.path.join(dest, new_path)
            shutil.copy2(file, h)
            file_increment += 1
    
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self)
    
    def function_call(self):
        self.model.copy_function(list_param)
        
        return

class View(tk.Tk)
    def __init__(self, controller)
        super().__init__()
        self.controller = controller
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.title('Minimal Reproducible Example')
        self.screen_output_holder = tk.StringVar()
    
        self._labels()
    
    
    def _labels(self):
        self.screen_output = ttk.Label(
                self, textvariable=self.screen_output_holder
            )
        self.screen_output.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Attempted approaches included making the model aware of the class View, which is not desirable.

The GUI should show:

```
Copying file 1 of 10...
Copying file 2 of 10...
Copying file 3 of 10...
...
...
```

Comment: Should `screen_output_var` be `self.screen_output_var` inside `copy_function()`?

Comment: @acw1668 good catch